# How to update/create a mysql stored procedure using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

My Question is: How to update or create MySQL stored procedure via VB.Net ?

Example:

MySQL Stored Procedure:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_tst`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'testing'
BEGIN 
   Select * from table1;
END

How to create the above stored procedure via VB.Net ?
(like we create / alter a table via VB.Net)

Comment: Execute CREATE PROCEDURE/ALTER PROCEDURE - like you create/alter tables)